# Не могу войти в ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, установка

Здраствуйте, когда устанавливал ubuntu на очередной pc нажал галку "автоматический вход", теперь никак нельзя войти, в прямом смысле, пишу пароль, жму enter, пароль правильный но в систему не входит. Просто возращает на выбор пользователя. Пробовал изменить пароль через рекавери, не помогло, потому что пароль верный, а в систему не входит. Ubuntu LTS 20.04

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у меня тоже была такая проблема. это вроде как баг. и надо ждать пока исправят.

Comment: @xverizex короче, легче переустановить)

Comment: Ну а `Ctrl+Alt+F1` работает? Войти можно?

Comment: у меня была похожая ситуация, причина - не грузился гном из-за одного самопального скрипта. Поэтому и выкидывало обратно на выбор юзера.

Comment: Ctrl alt f1 не работает

Comment: У меня была подобная ситуация, когда я выставил разрешение экрана, не поддерживаемое драйверами. Решил проблему, загрузившись через лайф-сиди и удалив конфиги в директории юзера (в моём случае они лежали в `~/.config/xfce4`, а где они у Гнома без понятия).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте войти в GRUB во время загрузки, а затем в однопользовательский режим (в конце строки linux.. добавить "1")

После этого можно попытаться восстановить пакет дисплей-менеджера, или попробовать найти параметр автозагрузки в конфигурационном файле, или просто переустановить менеджер входа